# installing osx with usb superdrive on a blanck new hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I have a MacBook Pro mid 2010 with a black hard drive on which I have to install OS X but my optical drive won't work so I'm trying to use a sub SuperDrive which isn't being recognized

Answer (score 1):

Seems like SuperDrive is not compatible with any MacBook Pro that already have built-in optical drive.
See here for statement from Apple:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202665

However there seems to be a way to override this according to this blog entry:
http://www.hardturm.ch/luz/2011/10/how-to-make-the-macbook-air-superdrive-work-with-any-mac/
Might be a bit complicated though.